# What does an default initialization of an array of shared_ptrs do?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, stdarray, make-shared

When I create an array of shared_ptrs to object `Foo`, what is actually being created?

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() x(3) : {};
  int x;
}

std::array<std::shared_ptr<Foo>, 10> arr_;
```

For instance, will the following code print 3?

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr = arr_[0];
std::cout << ptr->x;
```

Or do I first need to use `make_shared` and if so why?

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> ptr = arr_[0];
ptr = make_shared<Foo>();
std::cout << ptr->x;
```

Comment: What is being created when you create a `std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo;`? That, but 10 times. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

Comment: "`Foo() x(3) : {};`" - won't compile. I assume you meant `Foo() : x(3) {};`.

Answer (score 1):

> Constructs a `shared_ptr` with no managed object, i.e. empty
> `shared_ptr`.  ([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr))

So here's a small example to show that their default constructor stores `nullptr`.

```
#include <memory>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {};

int main()
{
    std::array<std::shared_ptr<Foo>, 10> arr_;
    for (const auto &obj : arr_) {
        std::cout << obj.get() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output

```
Program returned: 0
Program stdout
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

> For instance, will the following code print 3?

No, it will dereference a `nullptr` and this is an undefined behavior (Usually, it is likely to cause a crash).

Comment: Dereferencing a `nullptr` is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). There's no guarantee that it will cause a crash - anything could happen - it might even print "3" or the compiler might optimize the whole thing out so the program does nothing at all. It's undefined.

Answer (score 1):

> When I create an array of shared_ptrs to object Foo, what is actually being created?

Default constructed shared pointers will be created. Default constructed shared pointers are empty.

> For instance, will the following code print 3?

There's no guarantee that it will. If you indirect through an empty shared pointer, the behaviour of the program will be undefined.

> Or do I first need to use make_shared

That's a thing you can do.

> and if so why?

Because if you don't create a `Foo` object, then you cannot access a `Foo` object.